# Printing functions in different class

Tags: c#, printdocument

I need a small help. I want to make a simple class which have to be supplied only the data and the document is printed. I want to put all settings and graphics in one class and just call print function. My printdocument class looks something like this.

```
class printticket
{
    PrintDocument ticket; 

    public void printticket()
    {
        ticket = new PrintDocument();
    }

    public void writeHeader(string h)
    {
        Graphics g = printargs.Graphics;
        StringFormat fs = new StringFormat();
        fs.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(X, Y, pargs.MarginBounds.Width, (int)g.MeasureString(h, defaultFont).Height);
        g.DrawString(h, defaultFont, Brushes.Black, r, fs);
        Y += r.Height;
    }

    void print()
    {
        ticket.print();
    }
}
```

and now I want to call this function like this:

```
var printticket = new printticket();
printticket.writeHeader("this is a testing string");
printticket.print();
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: Sure I'd imagine it's possible. Did you try running that code? If so, what result did you get?

Comment: It should work the way it is. Did you try it?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016395/drawing-and-printing-complex-document-in-c-sharp-improving-replacing-my-printdo?rq=1

Comment: Remember, this is just a simple random code. I wsmt something that works like this.since the printargs is created only after print event, print args is here not set. @Ben Black

Comment: Okay, so you *want* code that works. Have you tried *running* any code yourself? If so, what code have you used. If not, why?

Comment: Ya actually full version of this code works. But then i need to call writeheader from within the printer.print+=(obj,e)->{}

Comment: @Ben Black can you please check the comment above this

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do it that I can think of is passing in the desired string you want to print out in the constructor of your `PrintTicket` class, which will be used later on in the `writeHeader` method. The `writeHeader` method is tied to the PrintPage event so it has access to the PrintPageEventArgs.

So your `PrintTicket` class would look something like:

```
public class PrintTicket {
    private PrintDocument _ticket;

    private string _header;
    private Font _defaultFont;

    private int X;
    private int Y;

    public PrintTicket(string header) {
        _ticket = new PrintDocument();
        _ticket.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.writeHeader);
        _header = header;
    }

    private void writeHeader(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e) {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        StringFormat fs = new StringFormat();
        fs.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(X, Y, e.MarginBounds.Width, (int)g.MeasureString(_header, _defaultFont).Height);
        g.DrawString(_header, _defaultFont, Brushes.Black, r, fs);
        Y += r.Height;     
    }

    public void Print() {
        _ticket.Print();
    }        
}
```

And you would call it like so:

```
PrintTicket t = new PrintTicket("This is what I want to print out");
t.Print();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But I need to call multiple methods (which i haven't included here). What would be a better soultion than this?

Comment: That would have been a great thing to include in the original question. Is there some reason you can't call these methods from within the method that is tied to the event?